# FutureBuilder Firestore Pagination

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement pagination in FutureBuilder I use SliverGrid I want to download 10 by 10 items when the user reaches the last row

Initially the user gets 10 documents, I want that when the user scroll down, he will get another 10 documents ,and start from the last document.

FutureBuilder, here I fetch data from Firestore then I use that data to build item inside SliverGrid

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'title',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      drawer: CustomDrawer(),
      body: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        future: database.fetchData(categoryChoosen),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return LoadingMainScreen();
          }

          List<Product> products = List<Product>();

          // add each product to the products list
          snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) {
            Product newProduct = Product.fromMap(doc);
            products.add(newProduct);
          });

          return CustomScrollView(
            slivers: <Widget>[
              _buildCategoryList(),
              _buildGridProductList(products),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add_shopping_cart,
          size: 30,
        ),
        onPressed: addProduct,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here, Fetch data by product category

```
class DatabaseService {
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;

  fetchData(String category) {
    if (category != 'all') {
      return _db
          .collection('products')
          .where('category', isEqualTo: category)
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
          .limit(10)
          .getDocuments();
    }
    return _db
        .collection('products')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .limit(10)
        .getDocuments();
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you continue with a detailed "this is what I observe and this is what I want to see instead"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it was a long time ago but if it can help someone else.
If you use Firestore then use the package Paginate_Firestore at this address [https://pub.dev/packages/paginate_firestore][1] and follow the steps:

```
 PaginateFirestore(
          query: yourQueryHere,
          itemsPerPage: 10,
          itemBuilderType: PaginateBuilderType.listView,
          isLive: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, snapshot, index) {
            if (snapshot.isNotEmpty) {
              return yourWidgetWithYourData(snapshot);
            } else {
              return const Loading();
            }
          }
```